# Check if request status is pending after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have an axios request:
`const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, payload);`. And I want to check after some timeout if this request is pending and do some logic.

Can I do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Promise.race`, you can make another Promise that resolves after 5 seconds, and check which resolves first.

```
Promise.race([
   axios.post(apiUrl, payload),
   new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000))
])
  .then((result) => {
    if (!result) {
      // 5 seconds timeout was reached
    }
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors); // don't forget this part
```